# what format can i save my 2 mb videos in mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, opencv, video-streaming, bson

so I am trying to build a server-client in which I am going to send multiple videos post request to the server and the server side is going to store it in the MongoDB database. I have done a similar program for image data and saved it in byte format but I am not sure how or what format I should use for videos. here is a code that I am using for my image data to eventually store it in the database i am using Locust for sending the request.

```
def training_task_2(self):
    if len(FD_list):
        ran_num = random.randint(0, 7)
        time.sleep(ran_num)
        try:
            with open(f"/Users/urooba/ramses/training_images/{FD_list[0]}", 'rb') as image:
                image_contents = image.read()
            data = {
                'event_name': 'FD',
            }
            file = {
                'input_image': image_contents
            }
            with self.lock:
                if len(FD_list):
                    self.client.post(url=self.host, files=file, data=data)
                    del(FD_list[0])

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"[EXCEPTION - FD] {e}")
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a the right tool for the job. I'd use a blob/file storage system and store the path to that object in mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Read it like you would any binary file, after all it is still binary data:

```py
with open(video_path, 'rb') as file:
    binary_data = file.read()
```

As for storing in **mongodb**, you might want to look into [GridFS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs) to know more about [storing Large vs Small binary data](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/#when-to-use-gridfs).